# When compiling a .c file, I get the following error: error: array type has incomplete element type

Tags: c, unix

Here's the line that is giving me the error

```
struct label labelArray[100];
```

I feel like it is not defined correctly.

Here's the rest of the code if it helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
int curr_addr = 0;
int is_instruction = 0;

struct label labelArray[100];

while(1) {
    char* buffer = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    if (getline(&buffer, &size, stdin) == -1) {
        // end of file
        break;
    } else {
        char* line = buffer;
        if (line[0] == '\t') {
            // ignore first tab
            line++;
        }

        const char *ptr = strchr(line, ':');
        if (ptr) {
            int endlabel = ptr - line + 2;
            line += endlabel;
        }
```

...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You need to show some more code for people to understand the error, else this question will get closed.

Comment: Did you define `struct label` before this line?

Comment: Actually, I change my mind. I voted to close but now I'm voting to reopen. I don't think any more code is needed to demonstrate this error message. In fact, [by attempting to compile it the error message is reproduced exactly](http://ideone.com/rQd03K)...

Comment: @NathanOliver What is necessary to form an MCVE? We must be able to reproduce the error message without modifying the code in any way, right? What's stopping you from reproducing the error message?

Comment: @Seb If that is the only code then yes the answer is simple.  We don't know if that is the only code or not.  It could be a simple typo but we cannot tell without an example of the code the OP is using.

Comment: @Seb, The problem is the OP said *"here is the line.."* and not *"here is my code.."*. So we know there is more code, that will surely make the problem more clearer.

Comment: @Seb even if the reason that the error occurs is that `label` is not defined, it could be because they forgot an `#include`, did not have the exact same name, etc. But if the reason is just not defining `label`, then this should be closed because the solution is probably not helpful ("define the structure").

Comment: @NathanOliver It's the only code required to produce the error message.

Comment: @Haris So this is what it's come to, people have to introduce a pointless main entry point to appease the pedants? Emphasis that the main entry point **is** pointless, because the error message clearly explains what the problem with that specific line is...

Comment: @crashmstr ... and how does having the full code make a difference? Can you tell the difference between forgetting a `#include`? Did you mean to suggest that "did not have the exact same name" (e.g. typographical error) is helpful to other users, but "not defining `label`" is not? I think you should review the close reasons quite carefully... Nonetheless, the "MCVE" close reason isn't and wasn't appropriate here.

Comment: @Seb having the full code makes a difference because we might have a *real* answer. But also that real answer may already exist for finding duplicates or to close as typo or other such things.

Answer (score 1):

You never defined `struct label`.  You can't define a variable of a given type without defining the type first.

Put the definition of `struct label` just before `main`.  Then you can create variables of that type.

Answer (score 1):

When you write the line

```
struct label labelArray[100];
```

you are declaring an array of structures in which each element is an exact copy of `struct label`. But to do that, first you need to declare `struct label`. You should declare it before the `main`.

If you cannot understand all that, in simple terms, you are trying to use a `struct` without declaring it. So, it is just like when you have not declared a variable and you use it, the compiler gives an error.

Also, see this: [Undefined Variable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936598/undefined-variable-error)

Comment: That link is for variables declared with `extern`, and does not apply here.